# typescript interface extends mock

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, typemoq

I have a typescript interface `cRequest` that's being passed as a type in a class method.
This interface also extends `express` Request type. What's the correct way to mock this in `jest` or `typemoq`?

```
import { Request } from 'express';
import { User } from '.';
export interface cRequest extends Request {
    context: {
        ID?: string;
        user?: string;
        nonUser?: string;
    };
    user?: User;
}
export default cRequest;
```

This is being used in a class method as follows

```
import { Response } from 'express';
public getData = async (req: cRequest, res: Response) => {}
```

And if i try to test it as follows it fails

```
const expRespMock: TypeMoq.IMock<Response> = TypeMoq.Mock.ofType<Response>();
const cReqMock: TypeMoq.IMock<cRequest> = TypeMoq.Mock.ofType<cRequest>();
await classObj.getData(cReqMock, expRespMock);
```

with the following message

```
  Argument of type 'IMock<cRequest>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'cRequest'.
  Property 'context' is missing in type 'IMock<cRequest>'.
```

What's the correct way to inject this interface mock into the method in tests?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this problem as follows

```
const cRequestStub= <cRequest> {};
```

And also it's now possible to selectively inject params as i need without any errors

```
const cRequestStub= <cRequest> {user: undefined}; or
const cRequestStub= <cRequest> {context: {ID: '', user: '', nonUser: ''}};

await classObj.getData(cRequestStub, expRespMock);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why to invent the wheel?
Jest has an interface that "decorates" given interface with the additional methods.

For example:

```
interface IRequest {
   req: string;
}

requestMock: jest.Mocked<IRequest>;
```

requestMock will have the IRequest interface + the mocks interface.

The simplest way to learn about new jest types is to check the source-code of the `@types/jest` lib, for example I've checked that is the return type of `jest.spyOn` and from that I've learned about `jest.Mocked<>`.

Comment: It doesn't have all the values from `Request` type from `express`. And this type has several values typed under it. So would be hard to specify each and every one of them with the correct types